# Word Macro for separating a comma-separated list to columns

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a very large set of data that represents cartesian coordinates in the form x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1...xn,yn,zn. I need to create a new line at the end of each xyz coordinate. I have been trying to record a macro that moves a certain number of spaces from the beginning of each line, then creates a new line. This, of course, will not work since the number of digits in each xyz coordinate differs.

How can I create a macro to do this in Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim t As String
    Dim I As Long
    s = "x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,xn,yn,zn"
    v = Split(s, ",")
    t = ""
    For I = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        t = t + v(I)
        If I Mod 3 = 2 Then
            t = t + vbCr
        Else
            t = t + ","
        End If
    Next I
    t = Left(t, Len(t) - 1)
    Debug.Print t
End Sub
```

The `Split` function splits a string along the delimiter you specify (comma in your case), returning the results in a 0-based array. Then in the `For` loop we stitch the pieces back together, using a carriage return (`vbCR`) every third element and a comma otherwise.

The final (optional) step is to remove the trailing carriage return.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The question placed before us was most clearly asked
“Please produce a macro sufficient to the task
I have Cartesian coordinates, a single line of these
Array them in many lines, triplets if you please!”

Instinctively we start to code, a solution for this quest
Often without asking, “Is this way truly best?”
But then another scheme arises from the mind
That most venerated duo: Word Replace and Find

Provide the two textboxes each an encantation
Check the Wildcard option and prepare for Amazation!

Forgive me!

1. In Word open Find/Replace
2. Click the `More` button and check the `Use wildcards` box
3. For `Find what` enter `([!,]{1,},[!,]{1,},[!,]{1,}),`
4. For `Replace with` enter `\1^p`
5. Use `Find Next`, `Replace` and `Replace All` as usual

**How it works**
With wildcards, `[!,]{1,}` finds one or more chars that are NOT commas. This idiom is repeated 3 times with 2 commas separating the 3 instances. This will match 3 comma-delimited coordinates. The whole expression is then wrapped in parentheses to created an auto-numbered group (in this case Group #1). Creating a group allows us to save text that matches the pattern and use it in the `Replace` box. Outside of the parentheses is one more comma, which separates one triplet of coordinates from the next.

In the `Replace` box `\1` retrieves auto-numbered group 1, which is our coordinate triplet. Following that is `^p` which is a new paragraph in Word.

Hope that helps!